# iptables v1.8.7 (nf_tables): unknown option "--dport"

Tags: linux, iptables

I need to route certain parts of my server through a USB network adapter. I decided to create a local proxy server, configure that to go through the correct interface and just route everything through that.

I've setup the proxy, but stuck on IP tables. So I need to route all connections to `127.0.0.1:3128` (my proxy) through network adapter `usb0` (`192.168.42.52`), and not the default `eth0`.

Command:

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING --dst 127.0.0.1 -p tcp --dport 3128 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.42.52:3128
```

Ubuntu 20.04 LTS, with default shipped kernel.

Comment: Considering your line works as-is on my system using iptables 1.8.7 (nf_tables), you have a non-stardard kernel or installation that you should describe sufficiently in your question to get more help: what distribution, what kernel version, is it a stock kernel or did you compile it yourself, what option did you use then etc. This comment only addresses the *title* of the question: the error. The full question itself probably requires additional ajustments.

Comment: @A.B I am using Ubuntu 20.04 LTS with the kernel it ships with, nothing special about my setup.

Comment: Can you try again by cut-pasting the line present on this page of UL SE (rather than any previous line in your CLI history)?

Comment: @A.B It has suddenly worked when prefixing it with sudo, is there a difference I should know about?

Comment: I didn't read correctly your reply: this command can work only when being root. Not using sudo makes it unfit for use. Even if the message isn't the correct message, reading any question about iptables assumes the OP to be root by whatever mean when using it.

Comment: Indeed I can reproduce your "problem" by typing /sbin/iptables (instead of iptables which shouldn't be available in the default PATH) as a normal (non root) user.